# WPF Bind to DependenyProperty

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I have a `DependenyProperty`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedBackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(CustomizedMetroTabItem), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

public Brush SelectedBackground
{
    get { return (Brush)GetValue(SelectedBackgroundProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedBackgroundProperty, value); }
}
```

I want to bind my `Background` property to the value of the SelectedBackgroud `DependenyProperty`

so I did the following:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding SelectedBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

I also tried

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{TemplateBinding SelectedBackground}"/>
```

But it doesnt work, why is that? (Ofcourse I set the SelectedBackground from the XAML)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a setter isn't part of the template, `TemplatedParent` won't work.

Use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}` to access the current object from a style setter.